# Setar uma classe css e renderizar o form em django

Tags: python, django, template, mtv

Criei a seguinte classe:

```
from django import forms

class FormDefault(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormDefault, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def renderFormGroup(self):
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row='<div class="form-group form-group-material" %(html_class_attr)s><label class ="control-label is-visible">%(label)s</label> %(field)s%(help_text)s</div>',
            error_row='%s',
            row_ender='</div>',
            help_text_html=' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
            errors_on_separate_row=True)
```

No meu construtor eu consigo setar em todos os campos do formulário a classe 'form-control', e para envolver os meus campos eu criei este método baseado no método "as_p"da classe "forms".

Assim ao colocar no meu template:

```
{{ form.renderFormGroup }}
```

Ele renderiza o fomulário como eu quero, com uma única exceção, eu não consegui setar uma classe no meu label.

Eu encontrei algumas soluções na internet para fazer um for no template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group form-group-material">
        <label class="control-label is-visible">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <span class="help-block">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Mas não queria fazer isso, queria renderizar direto da minha classe, colocando somente "form.renderFormGroup".

> A principio eu tentei alterar a string do "_html_output", mas o
>   "label" desta string é diferente do "label" do templante, enquanto no
>   template o "label" só é o texto do label, na string do "_html_output"
>   o "label" é a tag completa, depois tentei setar os valores no método
>   "label_tag", fiz um for no construtor pegando todos os boundfield e
>   tentei setar novamente modificando o "label_tag", mas não alterava
>   nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiquei mais ou menos dois dias correndo atrás destas resposta, fiz coisas mirabolantes no meu código para tentar resolver este problema, e no final descobrir que é algo super simples, é só colocar a seguinte linha no construtor:

```
self.required_css_class = 'control-label is-visible'
```

Então todas as classes que você atribui a "required_css_class" é renderizada no label, segue abaixo a classe completa:

```
from django import forms

class FormDefault(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormDefault, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.required_css_class = 'control-label is-visible'
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    def renderFormGroup(self):
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row='<div class="form-group form-group-material" %(html_class_attr)s>%(label)s %(field)s%(help_text)s</div>',
            error_row='%s',
            row_ender='</div>',
            help_text_html=' <span class="helptext">%s</span>',
            errors_on_separate_row=True)
```